# My counter won't stop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, range, counter

I don't know why but my counter won't stop although I think I have it coded right to stop after three iterations. Any ideas on why it wont work? @Ayush The counter is intialised to 1 at the beginning of the programme which is not included here. Where will I place the conditions? As I've tried using both "for counter in range(3) and while counter in range(3) however in the case of the while counter it runs for 3 iterations and then begins a fourth which gives me an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\Final Year Project\Build 6 (MiniMax input).py", line 311, in <module>
    print('The ' + turn + ' has been chosen this time, what move will they make first?!.')
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

@CyberGeekk.exe Here's a description of 'turn' and as turn = whoGoesFirst() I've included that aswell.

```
def whoGoesFirst():
     if (counter==1):
          if random.randint(1,1) == 0:
              return 'computer'
          else:
              return 'player'
     if (counter==2):
          if random.randint(1, 1) == 0:
              return 'computer'
          else:
              return 'player'
     if (counter==3):
          if random.randint(1, 1) == 0:
              return 'computer'
          else:
               return 'player'

theBoard = [' '] * 10
playerLetter, computerLetter = inputPlayerLetter()
turn = whoGoesFirst()
print('Now For Level ' +str(counter)+ '!!')
print('--------------------')
print('The ' + str(turn) + ' has been chosen to go first, what will they do?') 
gameIsPlaying = True

while gameIsPlaying:
    while counter in range(3):
    if turn == 'player':
        # Player's turn.
        drawBoard(theBoard)
        move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
        makeMove(theBoard, playerLetter, move)

        if isWinner(theBoard, playerLetter):
            counter=counter+1
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            print('--------------------')
            print("No, no! It cannot be! Somehow you tricked me, human. \n" 
                  "But never again! I, the computer,will increse my skill level for round "+str(counter)+" and beat you")
            print('--------------------')
            print('Now For Level ' +str(counter)+ '!!')
            #print('-------------------')
            gameIsPlaying = True
            theBoard = [' '] * 10
            playerLetter, computerLetter = inputPlayerLetter()
            turn = whoGoesFirst()
            print('The ' + turn + ' has been chosen this time, what move will they make first?!.')
            gameIsPlaying = True
```

Comment: Where is `counter` set, and to what value? You seem to be *adding* to `counter`, but checking that it's *less than or equal to* 4 - one of those is probably the wrong way around. And if you want to do something three times, why not `for _ in range(3):`?

Comment: If you want to make it stop after 3 iterations, it should be `if counter > 3` because `counter <= 4` will be true even when counter is 1 or 2 or 3. Also, where do you initialise the counter?

Comment: can you give a description of turn? that seems to be the crash issue

Comment: @CyberGeek.exe I've included what you've asked for in the original post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop breaks on `if (counter<=4):` because 1 is less then 4. To make the loop go 3 times, simply change the code on that line to look like this: `if (counter == 4):`. I tried this while commenting out all the unprovided methods and got the loop to go around 3 times.

Hope this helps you in your project, and please leave a comment if you need more help. Your welcome.

Comment: Yes thanks for that, needs a bit of polishing up but it seems to work fine so far!